# grep for lines containing two or more meaningful words

Tags: regex, grep, nlp

How can I use `grep` to find lines containing two or more meaningful words?

For example:

```
Blue Jewels  (good)
Interior (bad,one word)
Mercedes E270CDI - pic. 11 (bad, model name and not dictionary word)
A Walk in the Park (ok)
```

Comment: for make sense part, you need to use nltk parser. grep won't tell you that the matched word is meaningful or not.

Comment: I have (I hope!) editted your post to clarify it, but one point remains unclear: most the lines consist only of dictionary words, or must there be at least two such. Your example `Mercedes E270CDI - pic. 11` satisfies both conditions, if `pic` is in the dictionary, but what about `Mercedes E270CDI`, if `E270CDI` is not?

Comment: If your “dictionary” is very small – perhaps a few hundred words, I wouldn’t know – you can create a regex (and therefore use `grep`), but for natural languages I would expect both generating and compiling the vast regex to be impracticable.

Comment: P.S. My edit is still in the edit queue as of now.

Comment: Thanks for nltk. Read manual right now :)

Comment: user3447705, could you please add how your "grep" should look like what "sense" the tool should "see"? Note: I don't think the tags [tag:grep] and [tag:bash] are appropriate here.

Comment: Is your objective just to count how manny non-stopwords 'grams' do you have in each line? I would suggest just cleaning the stop works and tokenizing the line, then counting the tokens ;)

Comment: It might be in your interest to say how large and in what form your dictionary is, or otherwise specify what you mean by “meaningful”. On the other hand it could be interesting to have answers for both small (already provided) and large dictionaries.